# Import error from “Django Tutorial: a blog App” in windows 7

Tags: django

My blog app is under "mysite" project.
The error I get when I run the server with python manage.py runserver and I go to admin panel of django and then the error is

```
ImportError at /admin/

No module named dbe.blog

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    
Django Version:     1.5.1
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named dbe.blog

Exception Location:     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version:     2.7.2
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\farhan\\Downloads\\dist\\Django-1.5.1\\django\\bin\\mysite',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Sat, 17 Aug 2013 02:40:17 +0600
```

Comment: Post the full traceback so that we can know exactly where this import is failing. The traceback should be just below what you've posted, it starts from the line `Traceback (most recent call last):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspected you were using a tutorial, so after googling `dbe.blog tutorial` I found [this site](http://lightbird.net/dbe/blog.html). if that's what you are using, then I'm guessing the lines that refer to `dbe.blog` should, in your case, refer to `firstblog`. So `from dbe.blog import ...` should be `from firstblog import ...`. In your templates the same applies to the url tag

```
<a href="{% url dbe.blog.views.main %}" >Back to Blog Frontpage </a>
```

should be

```
<a href="{% url firstblog.views.main %}" >Back to Blog Frontpage </a>
```

Comment: hey guys I have forgot to say some thing now I have no blog application @vikki you are right I tried that tutorial then I deleted 'blog' application. But still getting error from 'blog' application. Now my application's name is 'firstblog' but here is no error from 'firstblog' application

Comment: Akhter, I believe the code in that tutorial has an error, as far as I can see, there's no blog app. So I think that was supposed to be dbe.blog. So just replace `blog.views...` with `firstblog.views...`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've added '"dbe.blog" to installed apps setting, try "blog" instead.

**EDIT:**

@vikki has a good point, so maybe you should give us full traceback.

Comment: if this was the case he would see the error the moment he tried to run the server and not when he goes to `/admin/`, in other words the server would not even run.

Comment: @AkhterAlaminFarhan did you uncomment "admin.autodiscover()" in urls module?

Comment: yup i did that @Maridev   
dpaste.com/1348140 here is my traceback vikki & maridev

Comment: hey guys i found that out thnx 4 your co-operation